# Закрашивание пересечения ромба и теругольника

Tags: java, graphics

Написал графическое приложение на `Java`, через главные пункты меню вызываются окна с параметрами рисования фигур (ромба, треугольника, эллипса). После задания параметров всех трех фигур они прорисовываются и содержимое треугольника закрашивается зеленым цветом (функция `InTriangle`). Написал также функицию принадлежности ромбу `InRhomb`, как функцию принадлежности одному из трегольников, разбиваемых диагональю ромба. В цикле по разрешенгию экрана проверяю принадлежности и ромбу и треугольнику (в случае такового закарашиваю зеленым цветом), но почему-то не закрашивается. Почему?

Привожу код моулей.

Модуль главного окна

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.draw;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    public static String strforlen;
    public static String strforangle;
    public static String strforx1;
    public static String strforx2;
    public static String strforx3;
    public static String strfory1;
    public static String strfory2;
    public static String strfory3;
    public static String strforx;
    public static String strfory;
    public static String strforwidth;
    public static String strforheight;
    public static Integer len;
    public static Integer angle;
    public static Integer x1;
    public static Integer x2;
    public static Integer x3;
    public static Integer y1;
    public static Integer y2;
    public static Integer y3;
    public static Integer x;
    public static Integer y;
    public static Integer width;
    public static Integer height;
    public static Integer Max(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
      Integer maximum;
      if (a>=b)
      {
          maximum=a;
      }
      else
      {
          maximum=b;
      }
      return maximum;
    }
    public static Integer Min(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
      Integer minimum;
      if (a<=b)
      {
          minimum=a;
      }
      else
      {
          minimum=b;
      }
      return minimum;
    }    
    public static Boolean InTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4)
    {
        Double a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4, a5, b5, a6, b6;
        Double crossingx12, crossingy12, crossingx23, crossingy23, crossingx31, crossingy31;
        a1=(double)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
        b1=y1-a1*x1;
        a2=(double)(y3-y2)/(x3-x2);
        b2=y2-a2*x2;        
        a3=(double)(y3-y1)/(x3-x1);
        b3=y3-a3*x3;
        a4=(double)(y4-y3)/(x4-x3);
        b4=y4-a4*x4;
        a5=(double)(y4-y1)/(x4-x1);
        b5=y4-a5*x4;        
        a6=(double)(y4-y2)/(x4-x2);
        b6=y4-a6*x4;     
        crossingx12=(b1-b4)/(a4-a1);
        crossingy12=a4*crossingx12+b4;
        crossingx23=(b2-b5)/(a5-a2);
        crossingy23=a5*crossingx23+b5;
        crossingx31=(b3-b6)/(a6-a3);
        crossingy31=a6*crossingx31+b6;
        Boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;
        flag1=(Min(x1,x2)<=crossingx12)&(crossingx12<=Max(x1,x2))&(Min(y1,y2)<=crossingy12)&(crossingy12<=Max(y1,y2));
        flag2=(Min(x2,x3)<=crossingx23)&(crossingx23<=Max(x2,x3))&(Min(y2,y3)<=crossingy23)&(crossingy23<=Max(y2,y3));
        flag3=(Min(x3,x1)<=crossingx31)&(crossingx31<=Max(x3,x1))&(Min(y3,y1)<=crossingy31)&(crossingy31<=Max(y3,y1));
        if (flag1&flag2&flag3)
                {
                   return true; 
                }
        else
                {   
                   return false;     
                }   
    }
    public static Boolean InRhomb(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4, int x5, int y5)
    {
        if (MainWindow.InTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x5, y5) | MainWindow.InTriangle(x1, y1, x4, y4, x3, y3, x5, y5))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowActivated(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenu1.setText("Нарисовать");

        jMenuItem1.setText("Ромб");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("Треугольник");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Эллипс");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Выход");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        SettingsOfRhomb rhombwindowsettings=new SettingsOfRhomb();
        rhombwindowsettings.setVisible(true);
        //SettingsOfTriangle trianglewindowsettings=new SettingsOfTriangle();
        //trianglewindowsettings.setVisible(true);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_formWindowActivated
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if ((!"".equals(strforlen)) & (!"".equals(strforangle)))
        {
            len=Integer.parseInt(strforlen);
            angle=Integer.parseInt(strforangle);
        }
        if ((!"".equals(strforx1))&(!"".equals(strforx2))&(!"".equals(strforx3))&(!"".equals(strfory1))&(!"".equals(strfory2))&(!"".equals(strfory3)))
        {
            x1=Integer.parseInt(strforx1);
            x2=Integer.parseInt(strforx2);
            x3=Integer.parseInt(strforx3);
            y1=Integer.parseInt(strfory1);
            y2=Integer.parseInt(strfory2);
            y3=Integer.parseInt(strfory3);
        }
        if ((!"".equals(strforx)) & (!"".equals(strfory)) & (!"".equals(strforwidth)) & (!"".equals(strforheight)))
        {
            x=Integer.parseInt(strforx);
            y=Integer.parseInt(strfory);
            width=Integer.parseInt(strforwidth);
            height=Integer.parseInt(strforheight);
        }
        MyPanel p=new MyPanel();
        //awtPanel a=new awtPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setSize(600, 800);
        //this.add(a);
        //this.repaint();
        this.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //a.setVisible(true);
        p.repaint();

    }//GEN-LAST:event_formWindowActivated

    private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem2ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        SettingsOfTriangle trianglewindowsettings=new SettingsOfTriangle();
        trianglewindowsettings.setVisible(true);        
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem2ActionPerformed

    private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem3ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        SettingsOfEllipse ellipsewindowsettings=new SettingsOfEllipse();
        ellipsewindowsettings.setVisible(true);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem3ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Модуль панели на которой происходит рисование

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.draw;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
public class MyPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form MyPanel
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Integer dx, dy;
        dx=(int)(MainWindow.len*Math.sin(180-(double)MainWindow.angle));
        dy=(int)(MainWindow.len*Math.cos(180-(double)MainWindow.angle));        
        if ((!"".equals(MainWindow.strforlen)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strforangle)))
        {
            g.drawLine(250, 250, 250, 250+MainWindow.len);
            //Integer dx, dy;
            //dx=(int)(MainWindow.len*Math.sin(180-(double)MainWindow.angle));
            //dy=(int)(MainWindow.len*Math.cos(180-(double)MainWindow.angle));
            g.drawLine(250, 250+MainWindow.len, 250+dx, 250+MainWindow.len+dy);
            g.drawLine(250+dx, 250+MainWindow.len+dy, 250+dx, 250+dy);
            g.drawLine(250+dx, 250+dy, 250, 250);
        }
        if ((!"".equals(MainWindow.strforx1)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strforx2)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strforx3)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strfory1)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strfory2)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strfory3)))
        {
            g.drawLine(MainWindow.x1, MainWindow.y1, MainWindow.x2, MainWindow.y2);
            g.drawLine(MainWindow.x2, MainWindow.y2, MainWindow.x3, MainWindow.y3);
            g.drawLine(MainWindow.x3, MainWindow.y3, MainWindow.x1, MainWindow.y1);
        }
        if ((!"".equals(MainWindow.strforx)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strfory)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strforwidth)) & (!"".equals(MainWindow.strforheight)))
        {
            g.drawOval(MainWindow.x, MainWindow.y, MainWindow.width, MainWindow.height);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int i=1; i<1000; i++)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=1000; j++)
            {
                if (MainWindow.InTriangle(MainWindow.x1, MainWindow.y1, MainWindow.x2, MainWindow.y2, MainWindow.x3, MainWindow.y3, i, j) & MainWindow.InRhomb(250, 250, 250, 250+MainWindow.len, 250+dx, 250+MainWindow.len+dy, 250+dx, 250+dy, i, j))
                        {
                            //g.setColor(Color.green);
                            g.drawLine(i, j, i, j);
                        }
            }
        }
    }
    public MyPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Также есть модули для окон, в которых задаются параметры рисования фигур. Их приводить не буду, чтоб не перезагружать вопрос кодом (елси кому надо приведу) и скажу, что в них происходит по нажатию кнопки запись в переменные

```
    public static String strforlen;
    public static String strforangle;
    public static String strforx1;
    public static String strforx2;
    public static String strforx3;
    public static String strfory1;
    public static String strfory2;
    public static String strfory3;
    public static String strforx;
    public static String strfory;
    public static String strforwidth;
    public static String strforheight;
```

главного окна введенных значений текстовых полей этих окон и затем дальнейшая конвертация их в соответствующие Integer переменные.

Comment: однозначно ответ - 42

Comment: вы и вправду уверены, что всем захочется читать такую простыню кода?

Comment: мне кажется, вам стоит поискать другое занятие, программирование не для вас

Answer (score 2):

Задачу однозначно можно решить проще и стандартными средствами, только работать придется с полигонами. Точно не скажу, но есть функция, которая закрашивает именно пересекающуюся область. Что касается кода, рекомендую почитать Java Code Convention, более подробно изучить язык и не использовать без необходимости static поля и static методы.